# ArcMap MXD into exe file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd, publishing, arcgis-publisher

Is there any way to make an ArcMap mxd doc into a simple exe file so that one who does not have ArcGIS can view my work?

Comment: I assume you don't have an ArcGIS online account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not an *.exe but you can either:

- export your map to a layered PDF so that anyone with the free Adobe Reader can view it
- use the Publisher extension to publish your map as a PMF so that anyone with the free ArcReader can view it

Comment: You can also export your pdf with layers that can be turned on and off in Adobe Reader. It's about the only thing you can change, but sometimes it's enough.

Comment: (almost) Everyone has a PDF viewer installed, which is great for viewing, from experience the ArcReader option is more useful. On your Esri install media you will find the installer and that will allow consumers of the PMF to do simple markups that can be re-imported into ArcGis (unlike pdf markups) and printed. It just depends on whether they want to *look* or *touch*.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to @PolyGeo's second suggestion, there is an extension called CarryMap.
It does what you exactly want. It exports your MDX into an exe file that can be opened with a double-click; no other software is needed. Furthermore, it exports your map for use in Android or iOS devices as well! However, you should pay to have the extension (commercial extension).

http://www.dataeast.com/en/carrymap.asp